# Header of a WP responsive theme won't properly remain on top at the top when scrolling; position:fixed and width:any% throws it out of whack

Tags: header, responsive-design, css-position, always-on-top

The WP responsive theme I'm working on:

http://www.wpexplorer.me/tetris/

I use Firebug for Firefox browser addon thingy to make changes before messing with the actual files. So if you have it or something similar, you will see that by adding position:fixed; to the #header section the header width shrinks well more than half its original size and the navigation menu is jacked up within the new shrunken space.

I have added other snippets of coding to the #header section like width:100%;, width:959px; and other percentages and pixels, which messes up the layout; especially when you resize the window down to what you would consider to be for a tablet and a mobile device - it's all out of whack. I can't get the sticky header for this theme to function or do right. Oh, I've also added z-index:200; to the #header section and margin:160px 0; to #main-content; these don't give me issues.

Adding the width: ; code to the #main-content doesn't seem to help either (which I read somewhere online that this was where the width code goes).

Anyway, does anyone know what code I need to make the header of this theme scroll up until it gets to the top of the page where it becomes sticky/static/fixed/on top (whatever the real term for it is) at all times? And, can you get it to work with the layout being in tact when the window is resized all the way down to the size of a mobile device?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```
#header-wrap{position:fixed;top:0;z-index:999;}
#pre-header{margin:20px 0 15px;width:960px;}
#main-content{margin:215px 0 30px;}
```

The position is fixed at the top using 0 with a z-index:999 you then need to set the width of the inner container pre-header 960px to match the rest.

You will need to setup the media queries for the other sizes you have setup. Easy, and Enjoy.

If you want the menu itself and not the social icons to become the top fixed bar without the social icons then you want to make a jquery scroll CSS change so that the #header becomes the fixed position.

It working with fixed header and social:

[image: WP Responsive Theme]

An illustration of it working without the social bar using a Jquery Scroll CSS change:

[image: Tetris WP Responsive Theme]

This is the way I would do it, I would move the menu down, and add the social icons to the menu itself. (Below is a screenshot of what I mean, the social icons are reduced to 75%)

[image: Fixed Menu Social Bar WP Responsive Theme]

PS. The social icons stand out to much so I would add a CSS3 Greyscale, and when the visitor hovers over them it turns on the color with a transition effect.
Hope this helps ;)

Comment: Nice ideas for the social icons! Thanks for looking into this for me. I was actually able to achieve this, but the header won't continue to scroll until it reaches the top of the page where I need it to become fixed, but only after it reaches the top when a visitor scrolls down like the header does on this site:http://demosthenes.info/blog/130/Scroll-To-Top-Then-Fixed-Effect-With-JQuery. I have tried their steps and it just doesn't work...unless I put the JQuery code in the wrong place or something *shrugs*. Any ideas on how to get it to work like that site?